# Brownie compiler remappings: "@"?

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts, brownie

In the doc'n:
[brownie compiler remappings](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compile.html#compile-remap)

for the file brownie-config.yaml

It gives two examples,
ex 1. has no "@" symbol:

```
compiler:
solc:
    remappings:
      - zeppelin=/usr/local/lib/open-zeppelin/contracts/
      - github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/=/usr/local/lib/dapp-bin/
```

ex 2. has an "@" symbol

```
compiler:
solc:
    remappings:
      - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.0.0"
```

What difference does the "@" symbol make? What is it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fist code snippet  specifies an import remapping for a directory named OpenZeppelin.

It remaps the ***zeppelin*** directory to ***/usr/local/lib/open-zeppelin/contracts/***. This means that when the Solidity compiler encounters an import statement like import ***"zeppelin/SomeContract.sol"***; in your code, it will actually look for the file ***/usr/local/lib/open-zeppelin/contracts/SomeContract.sol***.

The second code snippet specifies an import remapping for a **library** named OpenZeppelin.

Specifically, it remaps the **@openzeppelin** prefix to the URL OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.0.0. This means that when the Solidity compiler encounters an import statement like ***import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";*** in your code, it will actually fetch the file from the GitHub repository at https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/v3.0.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol.

In summary, the first remapping remaps a local directory to a specific file path on the filesystem, while the second one remaps a library prefix to a specific URL for fetching the library's files.